# How do I update my Info.plist file under Info Tab for specific target?

Tags: ios, xcode12, info-plist

When I select target and Info Tab, there I can see the short list of properties:

[image]

But when I select Info.plist from project navigator I can see long list of properties:

[image]

What makes the difference and why?

Under build settings and "Info.plist File" setting I have a path to the same file with long list of properties as it is previewed above.